# Proving only the summation part of Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you prove only the summation part of Cauchy-Schwarz?

What I mean is that $$\Bigl(\sum a_i b_i\Bigr)^2 \leq \sum a_i^2 \sum b_i^2.$$

I only want to show it for the case where $a_i , b_i \geq 0$ and $\sum a_i$ and $\sum b_i$ converge.

I tried to show it using the fact that the partial sums of each series will have an upper bound so that the maximal value each can be is $A$ and $B$ respectively, but I don't know how to show that $AB$ is the maximal value for their product.

Comment: You may find https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=lbWSVNr7JIPaarbrgrAM&url=http://rgmia.org/papers/v12e/Cauchy-Schwarzinequality.pdf&ved=0CBoQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGGiKGgZJ1AIsDoLH6PHNguj7czqg useful.

Comment: Do you want to prove the series case *using* the finite sums case?

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum a_{i}b_{i}=0$ is trivial, so assume $\sum a_{i}b_{i}\neq0$
  and so $a_{i}\neq0$
  for some $i$
  and $b_{j}\neq0$
  for some $j$
 . Let $t>0.$
  We have $$0\leq\sum\left(a_{i}-tb_{i}\right)^{2}=\sum a_{i}^{2}+t^{2}\sum b_{i}^{2}-2t\sum a_{i}b_{i}$$
 hence$$\sum a_{i}b_{i}\leq\frac{\sum a_{i}^{2}}{2t}+\frac{t\sum b_{i}^{2}}{2}.$$
 Now take $$t=\frac{\sqrt{\sum a_{i}^{2}}}{\sqrt{\sum b_{i}^{2}}}$$
 and you have your inequality. Note that if $a_{i}\geq0$
  and $\sum a_{i}<\infty$
  then $\sum a_{i}^{2}\leq\left(\sum a_{i}\right)^{2}<\infty$
  and $$\sum\left(a_{i}-tb_{i}\right)^{2}\leq\sum\left(2\max\left\{ a_{i},tb_{i}\right\} \right)^{2}=\max\left\{ 4\sum a_{i}^{2},4t^{2}\sum b_{i}^{2}\right\} <\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{\sum a_i^2 \sum b_i^2}$ is a upper bound of the partial sums of $\sum a_i b_i$.